# Unable to get input to store in a buffer in a x86asm kernel im making

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

all it does is save the last character typed

```
prompt:
    call print_string
    .input_loop:
    call wait_for_keypress
    cmp al, 13 ; checks if enter pressed
    je .exit
    mov [input_buffer], al ; Store the read character in the buffer         
    mov ah, 0x0E    ; Function 0Eh of interrupt 10h (teletype output)
    mov al, [input_buffer] ; Load the character from the buffer
    mov bh, 0       ; Page number (0 for default)
    mov bl, 7       ; Text attribute (7 is white on black)
    int 10h         ; Call interrupt 10h

    mov [input_buffer], al ; Store the read character in the buffer
    jmp .input_loop
    .exit:
        ret
```

I tried a lot of stuff like editing the code, also tried to use chatgpt, (it did not help).

It is supposed to store the entire input in the buffer.

Comment: Are You creating a botloader and want to run it in qemu or something?

Comment: yes, i already have the bootloader im just makign the kernel

Comment: `input_buffer`'s address never changes so when you write to the buffer it will always be the last character typed that shows up in the first byte. Just before `.input_loop:` you could move the address of `input_buffer` into a register like `di` with `mov di, input_buffer` and then use `di` instead of `input_buffer`in the rest of the code. After reading a character you'd increment `di` with `inc di` to advance to the next position in the buffer for the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

### A quick review

> ```
> 1. mov [input_buffer], al ; Store the read character in the buffer         
> 2. mov ah, 0x0E    ; Function 0Eh of interrupt 10h (teletype output)
> 3. mov al, [input_buffer] ; Load the character from the buffer
> 4. mov bh, 0       ; Page number (0 for default)
> 5. mov bl, 7       ; Text attribute (7 is white on black)
> 6. int 10h         ; Call interrupt 10h
> 7. mov [input_buffer], al ; Store the read character in the buffer
> ```

- Line 3 is redundant because the AL register still contains the value that line 1 stored in the input buffer.
- Lines 4 and 5 that load the high and low bytes of the same word-sized register could and should get combined into a single load of the word-sized register.
- Line 7 is again redundant because the input buffer still contains the value that line 1 had put there. Remember that an instruction like `mov al, [input_buffer]` only takes a **copy of the value** in the memory variable; it does **not remove the value** from the memory variable.

### Solving it

In the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983626/unable-to-get-input-to-store-in-a-buffer-in-a-x86asm-kernel-im-making#comment135715267_76983626), @MichaelPetch already hinted a solution.

Your *input_buffer* comprises multiple bytes. You need to store the key in a *current location* within the buffer and then set up so that the next key will land in the *next higher location*. To this effect, you can use a **pointer** to a current location (as Michael suggested) or you could use an **offset** to a current location. In the below code I use the 'offset'-method. It's nice that at the conclusion of the input, the DI register will contain the length of the string, so the number of stored characters.

```
prompt:
    call print_string
    xor  di, di      ; CURRENT OFFSET IN THE BUFFER
.input_loop:
    call wait_for_keypress  ; -> AX (if obtained from MOV AH=00h : INT 16h)
    cmp  al, 13      ; checks if enter pressed
    je   .exit
    mov  [input_buffer + di], al ; Store the read character in the buffer         
    inc  di          ; NEXT CURRENT OFFSET IN THE BUFFER
    mov  bx, 0x0007  ; BH PageNumber, BL TextAttribute (WhiteOnBlack)
    mov  ah, 0x0E    ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  10h
    jmp  .input_loop
.exit:
    ret
```

The 'offset'-method is also helpful if you want to guard against overflowing your buffer (inputting more characters than the buffer can hold), because you could write it the following way:

```
prompt:
    call print_string
    xor  di, di      ; CURRENT OFFSET IN THE BUFFER
.input_loop:
    call wait_for_keypress  ; -> AX (if obtained from MOV AH=00h : INT 16h)
    cmp  al, 13      ; checks if enter pressed
    je   .exit
    mov  [input_buffer + di], al ; Store the read character in the buffer         
    inc  di          ; NEXT CURRENT OFFSET IN THE BUFFER
    mov  bx, 0x0007  ; BH PageNumber, BL TextAttribute (WhiteOnBlack)
    mov  ah, 0x0E    ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  10h
    cmp  di, ...     ; FILL IN A NUMBER, COMPARE TO THE SIZE OF YOUR BUFFER
    jb   .input_loop ; CONTINU WHILE THERE'S ROOM IN THE BUFFER
.exit:
    ret
```